# connection checking & disable script if lcd has rebooted 3 times in the same day

Tags: scripts

i set the crontab which will run at the 30th minute and will trigger the script and in the script i make the lcd will reboot if it does not get the connection
my question is :

1. can it check the connection every 30 minutes in the script without set up time in crontab?
2. how to make a script that checks the connection for 30 minutes or 1 hour and if during that time does not get the connection then the lcd will automatically reboot
3. how do i disable the script if lcd has rebooted 3 times in the same day?

```
if ! ping -c 5 google.com; then
sudo ifconfig wlp2s0 down
sudo reboot
sleep 5
sudo ifconfig wlp2s0 up
fi
```

Comment: Lets see the script you have already written and maybe someone can point out any errors. No one will write the script for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read `man -a crontab`. It's easy to run your script every 30 minutes, and is what `cron`, controlled by your `crontab` file, is designed for.

Commands in your script after `sudo reboot` are not run. The reboot kills everything. Change the Network Configuration of `wlp2s0`'s to have the "Auto" box checked. Then it will be brought up as part of system startup. Also, the "`sudo ifconfig wlp2s0 down`" is unnecessary, as rebooting will do it
Use `shutdown`, rather than `reboot`. Read `man shutsown`.

Keeping a count of reboots in an extetnal file is easy, too. **Fragmentary code, untested, not even shellchecked**

```
# at beginning of script
# reboot_file name changes daily
reboot_file="/tmp/reboot.$(date "+%F")`
max_reboots=3
  
[[ ! -f "$reboot_file" ]] && echo "0" >"$reboot_file"
reboot_count="$( cat "$reboot_file")"

...

# later on, just before rebooting 
let reboot_count++
if [[ "$reboot_count" -le "$max_reboots" ]] ; 
then
  echo "$reboot_count" >"$reboot_file"
  flush
  sudo shutdown -r now 
# execution stops here due to reboot
fi
# if we get here there have been too many reboots
# what do you want to do?
sudo shutdown -h now "Too many reboots"
```

Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: how to change the network configuration to be auto checked?and i just paste your code to the new file without the last line?and where can i get a **reboot file**? @Waltinator